# gradle build fails cannot find sonar plugin "sonar-runner"

Tags: gradle, plugins, sonar-runner

My gradle project cannot build. It fails with `Plugin with id 'sonar-runner' not found.`

Here's my build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
}
```

I've refreshed my Gradle project. Then I've deleted my ~/.gradle/caches folder, but didn't work. Then I deleted my entire ~/.gradle folder, still the same error.

Any ideas please?

It's funny that gradle build doesn't run and gives me that exception, but bash gradle build runs fine, can someone clarify the difference in between? Thanks. My setup is on Mac OSX 10.11.6.

Comment: Is that the entire build.gradle in the root project? Are you pointing to any repositories to pull the plugin?

Comment: Thanks for poking. I found it's pulling from my company repo: ```buildscript {
 apply from: "http://dev-resource.abc-company.net/something-builds/0.11.0.RELEASE/repository.gradle?jn=${java.net.URLEncoder.encode(System.getenv()['JOB_NAME'] ?: 'NOJOB', 'UTF-8')}", to: it
}

apply from: "http://dev-resource.abc-company.net/something-builds/0.11.0.RELEASE/buildscripts.gradle?jn=${java.net.URLEncoder.encode(System.getenv()['JOB_NAME'] ?: 'NOJOB', 'UTF-8')}"```, so, is it something in the repo messed up/missing?

Comment: It may not be the company repo. Can you update your answer with the `repositories {}` section? Also, are you by any chance calling `URLClassLoader` in the main projects `build.gradle`?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have a `repositories{}` section in my build.gradle.

Comment: So what repository are you going to grab the `sonar-runner` plugin from?

Comment: from one of the builds in `http://dev-resource.abc-company.net/something-builds/0.11.0‌​.RELEASE`, anyway, I was able to run it via `bash gradle build`,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Analyzing+with+Gradle:

> Users of Gradle Sonar or Sonar Runner Plugins ? The existing Gradle
>   Sonar Runner and Gradle Sonar plugins, which are part of the Gradle
>   distribution, should no longer be used (See this official note from
>   the Gradleware team). The use of the Gradle SonarQube plugin is
>   recommended instead.

You have to use it as described at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube
Build script snippet for use in all Gradle versions:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

Build script snippet for new, incubating, plugin mechanism introduced in Gradle 2.1:

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
}
```

Issue discussing this problem:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/plugin-with-id-org-sonarqube-not-found/11588/10